# Javascript forEach an Array of Object recursive

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

i need some help at looping over an Object with Array of Objects


**Here is an example Object:**

```
const node = {
    documents: [{
        name: "test1"
    }],
    children: [{
        documents: [{
            name: "test2"
        }],
        children: [{
            documents: [{
                name: "test3"
            }],
            children: []
        }]
    }]
};
```

**My Problem**

I tried some of the solutions from here but it's not quite what I need. Basically i want to move every object from the documents Array into the childrens Array.

I already got that but currently its only doing it in the firts Object so not recursive...

I cant figure it out without creating an Frankenstein-ish code...

**I tried**
like i mentioned before i used

```
Array.concat()
```

to append documents to children but only in the first Object.

**What it should look like**

```
const node = {
    children: [
    {
    name: "test1"
    },
    {
    children: [
        {
      name: "test2"
      },
      {
      children: [
        {name: "test3"}
      ]
      }
    ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Now in every "depth" the documents were "appended" to children.

And that should happen for every children key (depth).


Is someone kind enough to help me out?

## EDIT:

I guess my example is not good enough. Here is some actual data:

```
      const node = {
        id: 1,
        name: "Root Node",
        documents: [
          { name: "Doc Root 1", id: 1234 },
          { name: "Doc Root 2", id: 1235 }
        ],
        children: [
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "Sub Node Node1",
            documents: [
              { name: "Doc SubNote 1 1", id: 1236 },
              { name: "Doc SubNote 1 2", id: 1237 }
            ],
            children: [{
              id: 3,
              name: "Sub Sub Node Node 1",
              documents: [
                { name: "Doc SubSubNote 1 1", id: 1238 },
                { name: "Doc SubSubNote 1 2", id: 1239 }
              ],
              children: null,
              addTreeNodeDisabled: true,
              addLeafNodeDisabled: true,
              editNodeDisabled: true,
              delNodeDisabled: true,
            }],
            addTreeNodeDisabled: true,
            addLeafNodeDisabled: true,
            editNodeDisabled: true,
            delNodeDisabled: true,
          }
        ],
        addTreeNodeDisabled: true,
        addLeafNodeDisabled: true,
        editNodeDisabled: true,
        delNodeDisabled: true,
      };
```

Comment: do `documents` can have childrens?

Comment: no documents is always an array with objects

Comment: the data structure is quite mixed up. please add the wanted result of it.

Comment: Sorry for that, I messed up the export :(
Now its a better example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could concat a copy of documents with the childrens by calling the function again.

```js
var f = ({ documents, children, ...o }) => {
        children = [...(documents || []), ...(children || [])].map(f);
        return children.length
            ? { ...o, children }
            : o;
    },
    data = { id: 1, name: "Root Node", documents: [{ name: "Doc Root 1", id: 1234 }, { name: "Doc Root 2", id: 1235 }], children: [{ id: 2, name: "Sub Node Node1", documents: [{ name: "Doc SubNote 1 1", id: 1236 }, { name: "Doc SubNote 1 2", id: 1237 }], children: [{ id: 3, name: "Sub Sub Node Node 1", documents: [{ name: "Doc SubSubNote 1 1", id: 1238 }, { name: "Doc SubSubNote 1 2", id: 1239 }], children: null, addTreeNodeDisabled: true, addLeafNodeDisabled: true, editNodeDisabled: true, delNodeDisabled: true, }], addTreeNodeDisabled: true, addLeafNodeDisabled: true, editNodeDisabled: true, delNodeDisabled: true, }], addTreeNodeDisabled: true, addLeafNodeDisabled: true, editNodeDisabled: true, delNodeDisabled: true },
    result = f(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That is very good but I have an error.
in some cases children can be null and it throws an length is undefined error.

Comment: add (children && children .length) instead of children .length

Comment: Can you have a look at my Edit?
I cant get your code to run with this data.
It runs, but is loses some keys :(

Answer (score 2):

I've used recursion here to achieve the results.

```js
const node = {"documents":[{"name":"test1"}],"children":[{"documents":[{"name":"test2"}],"children":[{"documents":[{"name":"test3"}],"children":[]}]}]}

const unwrap = (v) => ({...{...v}[0]});

const merge = (node) => ([...node.documents, {children: (unwrap(node.children).hasOwnProperty("children") ? merge(unwrap(node.children)) : node.children) }]);

console.log(merge(node));
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you can try with the data from my edit.
I cant get yours to work :(

Comment: the datasets are nowhere near the same, i suggest you add a different question for that, and add a smaller object with clear and exact data structure.